# How to space inline-flex divs evenly?

Tags: html, css

So I have 3 same class divs and I want them to be evenly spaced in the same line.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="group-4">
                                            <div class="group-5">
                                                <div class="text-wrapper-5">Hesapla</div>
                                                <div class="group-6">
                                                    <div class="img-wrapper"><img class="img" src="img/case.svg"></div>
                                                    <div class="text-wrapper-6">Some Context</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <p class="p">
                                                    A tristique facilisi gravida at felis. Sed ornare arcu, tortor hendrerit etiam vulputate
                                                    libero tellus. Etiam nu
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.group-4 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 186px;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.group-5 {
    position: relative;
    width: 316px;
    height: 186px;
}

.text-wrapper-5 {
    position: relative;
    top: 162px;
    left: 49px;
    font-family: "Inter-Bold", Helvetica;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #ff611e;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 0.46px;
    line-height: 24px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.group-6 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 314px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Here is a photo of the current site.
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTQ4R.png)

I'm not really experienced in CSS but I tried inline-flex display mode which didn't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this pretty quickly with flexbox. You probably want to remove `position: relative` from `.group-5`, and then change `.group-4` to `display: flex` and maybe add `align-items: center`, but that might not be needed. I would also remove the `position` and `display` properties from `.group-6` as I don't think those are doing anything for you currently. You did not post all your HTML, but assuming that `.group-5` repeats 3 times, making those changes will give you what you want. Unrelated to your question, but you should always use a 100% safe fallback font when you declare your `font-family` stack (like in `.text-wrapper-6`, usually the font type like `sans-serif`. Take a look here:

```css
.group-4 {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    height: 186px;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.group-5 {
    width: 316px;
    height: 186px;
}

.text-wrapper-5 {
    position: relative;
    top: 162px;
    left: 49px;
    font-family: "Inter-Bold", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #ff611e;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 0.46px;
    line-height: 24px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.group-6 {
    width: 314px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="group-4">
  <div class="group-5">
    <div class="text-wrapper-5">Hesapla</div>
    <div class="group-6">
      <div class="img-wrapper"><img class="img" src="img/case.svg"></div>
      <div class="text-wrapper-6">Some Context</div>
    </div>
    <p class="p">
      A tristique facilisi gravida at felis. Sed ornare arcu, tortor hendrerit etiam vulputate
      libero tellus. Etiam nu
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="group-5">
    <div class="text-wrapper-5">Hesapla</div>
    <div class="group-6">
      <div class="img-wrapper"><img class="img" src="img/case.svg"></div>
      <div class="text-wrapper-6">Some Context</div>
    </div>
    <p class="p">
      A tristique facilisi gravida at felis. Sed ornare arcu, tortor hendrerit etiam vulputate
      libero tellus. Etiam nu
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="group-5">
    <div class="text-wrapper-5">Hesapla</div>
    <div class="group-6">
      <div class="img-wrapper"><img class="img" src="img/case.svg"></div>
      <div class="text-wrapper-6">Some Context</div>
    </div>
    <p class="p">
      A tristique facilisi gravida at felis. Sed ornare arcu, tortor hendrerit etiam vulputate
      libero tellus. Etiam nu
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want a better look at this where you can expand the screen and actually see it demo'd, you can [check out my codepen demo here](https://codepen.io/stephenirving/pen/eYXjwwQ) or you can view the [fullscreen Codepen example without the code](https://codepen.io/stephenirving/live/eYXjwwQ).

As a final note, I would also recommend trying to come up with more descriptive names for your classes than just `.group-#`. That can get pretty confusing and giving them better names will remove some of the mental overhead when you're trying to style them.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

Set the outer div containing the 3 divs to be display flex. set another property on this outer div which is flexDirection: row. Then add another property justifyContent: center (or set it to space-evenly) and alignItems: center.

Comment: The properties should not be in camelCase in normal css, they should be hyphen delimited like `flex-direction`. He already has `justify-content: space-evenly` in his code. `flex-direction: row` is the default setting when using flexbox and thus there is no need to set it explicitly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).